# Как установить сертификат пользователя, для доступа к проекту

Tags: vpn

Проблема в том, что при установке сертификата я получаю следующую ошибку
Для доступа пользуюсь FortiVpn
Vpn перестал подключаться через некоторое время работы и при переустановке сертификата появляется ошибка, которую приложил на скриншоте

Пробовал переустановить сертификат, но получаю ошибку со скриншота
Пробовал удалить сначала Forti vpn и потом установить сертификат, но тоже получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вводите правильный пароль.

Comment: Я устанавливаю новый сертификат, поверх старого удаленного. И ввожу новый, правильный пароль, но ошибка сохраняется

Comment: Вы пароль вручную вводите или копипастите из блокнота? Из блокнота если копипастить может символ конца строки захватывать